# Attaching PDF without saving document using SyncFusion C#.net

Tags: c#, syncfusion

Can someone help me or give me a link on how to attach a PDF to email using syncfusion html to pdf converter without saving the document?

here is my code:

```
//Convert URL to PDF
PdfDocument doc = htmlConverter.Convert(render_to_html(Panel_preview_attachment), baseUrl);

doc.Save(path + "Attachments\\" + file_name); //I need to remove this

string empPdf = path + "Attachments\\" + file_name;

LinkedResource linkedresource = new LinkedResource(empPdf, "application/pdf");
linkedresource.ContentId = "empPdf";
linkedresource.ContentType.Name = file_name;
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(linkedresource);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert HTML to PDF and send the PDF document in a mail without saving it to a filesystem. We can save the PDF document to the memory stream and we can send it to a mail. Please refer below link for more information,

**HTML to PDF**: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/webkit

**Email output PDF**: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/6064/how-to-create-pdf-dynamically-and-email-as-attachment

**Note** : I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: thank you gowtham raj. I already tried using memory stream to save. And then i attach this in my linked resource and was able to send it properly in an email. The problem I have now encountered is the PDF could not be loaded properly. I'll try to attach a screenshot here.

Comment: Cannot attach the image.

the error is:

Adobe acrobat reader could not open 'test.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).